# Rails 3: What is the difference between an Engine and a Gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

What is the difference between the two and when one should be used instead of the other?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

An `Engine` in rails terminology is a actually a subapplication of a web-application. For instance, something like a blog, a forum, or simple authentication: these are not full-blown applications, but pages/views/controllers/models that can be added to any rails application.

In rails2 this would be done using a `plugin`. Now since rails3 an engine can be packaged in a `gem`.

A `gem` is a ruby library, which can be found on http://rubygems.org and it is the standard (only) way to package and distribute ruby code to other rubyists.

So to conclude:

- A gem: is a generic library, which can be easily installed, which are version-managed, have dependencies and such.
- An engine: is a sub-application of a Rails application, and since Rails 3 these are distributed as a gem (which is awesome!).

So when will you use one or the other:

- create a gem if you want to share ruby-functionality
- create an engine (and package it in a gem) if you have parts of your rails application that can be used more generally.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks. one more question: the apps we use such as Hoptoad, exceptional, newrelic, etc, are they gems or engines? thanks

Comment: They are all gems. A gem can easily tie in to Rails, by implementing a class called `Railtie`. This means it can tie in functionality into rails. If it implements a class called `Engine` it can offer more: models, views, controllers, and since rails 3.1 also assets like stylesheets, javascripts, ... The gems you mention all implement the `Railtie` to bind into Rails. This means that these are ment to be used together with Rails. So depending on the functionality you offer to Rails you have the option to either create a `Railtie` or `Engine`.

Comment: If the functionality you want to add in the gem, is not directly dependant on Rails (you do not hook into any of the classes), you create a normal gem. E.g. Nokogiri is such an example. But, to conclude, since rails 3 you will always use a gem to extend rails. This is also why bundler has become so important.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, very good. As a last one, can you mention some resources related to gems and engines? Thanks!

Comment: For creating gems, I use jeweler. For more info on Railties/Engines, check: http://www.themodestrubyist.com/2010/03/01/rails-3-plugins---part-1---the-big-picture/ and https://gist.github.com/af7e572c2dc973add221 (from the creator of enginex, which you best use until rails 3.1)