# Using an engine, or a library gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rails-engines

I wanted to separate out common models (and their migration) out to a gem. I was wondering if I should an engine, or make a library gem for this purpose.

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6815401/rails-3-what-is-the-difference-between-an-engine-and-a-gem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Engines are great for providing a full MVC stack. If you plan on adding more than common models it is a very clever move since it will add a lot of flexibility to your application.

Otherwise you may find the workflow over head to much compare to the functionality provided.

Comment: Thanks! I was planning of adding a 'Core' app, which would have my common models (+ authentication).

Comment: Would you recommend this to be a library? If so, how would I expose my migrations for those particular models. Would they need to be installed via a rake command, similar to the one engines command?

Comment: I would use an Engine for your models, migrations and perhaps controllers related to it. Also routes ;)