# How to write a gem? Preparing with 'lib' directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Can you explain a few moments? I want to create a gem, just for me, just for self-study.

For this, i write gem`s code in 'lib' folder, where i can test it in my app.

For now, i have next questions:

1. How i can extend 'views'? I want to create separate layout.
2. How i can extend controllers? For example - applications controller, i want to extend it with a few methods.

For now i already extended my User model, something like this:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  require 'auth'
...



#lib/auth.rb
class User
  require 'digest'

  before_save :encrypt_password

  def xxx
....
```

is it right way?

For now, i need to extend application controller and add another application layout, but do not know how.

Comment: I think you actually want to make an "engine" and package it as a gem.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6815401/rails-3-what-is-the-difference-between-an-engine-and-a-gem

Comment: You can write a gem and just build it from source which will be a local folder, here is a cool tutorial about how to build a gem http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=build+ruby+gemCreate+a+Ruby+Gem%3A+Real-world+play+by+play.+Part+1

Comment: As i understand, i can use this - http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check out a [gem I made](https://github.com/richpeck/exception_handler) if you like

--

**Gems**

Rails gems are basically just zip-files for your Rails app

When you "install" a rails gem, the gem files inside the gem  will actually be put into your Rails application. Take our gem as an example:

[image]

The folders marked in Red will be inserted into your Rails application when you install the gem. You can't see them, but they'll be there

---

**Engine**

It's my opinion that the majority of Rails `gems` will be [`engines`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html):

This means that whenever you create a `gem`, all you're doing is creating a specific piece of functionality which can be applied to your application as required

A gem will create a `module`, which will wrap all your `gem`'s functionality. This `module` will be defined in the `lib` file you created, and therefore allow you to extend your `gem`'s functionality by inheriting from this module

---

**Views / Controllers**

To create `views` / `controllers` in your application, you need to remember what I said - the files from your `gem` will be placed into your app

With that in mind, the way to do it is to create an `/app` folder, and then put the `views` or `controllers` directories in there:

[image]

You basically need to create directories which inherit from the module you define in the `lib` directory of your gem:

```
-app
|-controllers
|--exception_handler
|---exception_controller.rb

|- views
|-- exception_handler
|--- exception
|---- show.html.erb

-lib
|-exception_handler.rb #-> ExceptionHandler module
```

This is exactly the same as if you [namespace](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing) your routes

--

As I've created a gem, you may be best talking to me directly about the process. You can post a comment if you'd like to talk about it further